# Terminating current active connection due to forced scale event

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, aws-aurora-serverless

We use AWS Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL as the main database in our project.
With a growing number of users, we started facing the following issue quite often:
`terminating current active connection due to forced scale event.`

Obviously, it happens when the database is scaling, but I'm not sure how to properly handle this exception or prevent scaling.

Also, it seems that when we save a considerable number of rows in one transaction and scaling begins, some rows are committed to the database and others aren't, which breaks the data consistency.

We use C# Entity Framework Core as ORM.

Is there a proper way to handle situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [switch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade.html#aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade-from-serverless-v1-procedure) to v2 to avoid terminating active connections during scaling. As the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.scaling) states,

> The notions of scaling points and associated timeout periods from
> Aurora Serverless v1 don't apply in Aurora Serverless v2. Aurora
> Serverless v2 scaling can happen while database connections are open,
> while SQL transactions are in process, while tables are locked, and
> while temporary tables are in use. Aurora Serverless v2 doesn't wait
> for a quiet point to begin scaling. Scaling doesn't disrupt any
> database operations that are underway.

If you are going to stick with V1 (might not be possible for much longer due to [end-of-life](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.MySQL56.EOL.html) for V1), you can also change the [setting](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html) to "Roll back" rather than "force":

> If the timeout expires before a scaling point is found, do this:
>
> Roll back the capacity change Your Aurora Serverless cluster's
> capacity isn't changed. It stays as its current capacity.
>
> Force the capacity change Your Aurora Serverless cluster's capacity is
> changed without a scaling point. This can interrupt in-progress
> transactions, requiring resubmission.

You can see the current timeout action in the CLI with:

```
aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier myCluster | 
jq .DBClusters[].ScalingConfigurationInfo.TimeoutAction
```

and set it with

```
aws rds modify-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier myCluster --scaling-configuration TimeoutAction=RollbackCapacityChange
```

Comment: How Aurora v2 handles the situations like this?

Comment: @GrigoryZhadko I updated the answer to discuss scaling in V2.